# Printing with loop from JSON File

Tags: python, arrays, json, loops

I have the following data taken from an API. I am trying to access the "transcript" parts using a Python script with a loop. My aim is to print all "transcript" plain text. I working on that still, I have this error:

`TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.`

**code:**

```
import json
filename = "1transcript.json"

with open(filename, "r") as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for output in data['results']:
 print(output['alternatives']['transcript']) #updated
```

**json:**

```
{
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1p1beta1.LongRunningRecognizeResponse",
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.9172556,
          "transcript": "The Joe Rogan Experience reacting to him knocking out volkov. This is one of my favorite one of my favorite Clips because that knockout was so crazy. We were in the middle here is or here. I'm so too right now, Jamie."
        }
      ],
      "languageCode": "en-us"
    },
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.7491517,
          "transcript": " Yeah, I just airdrop tattoo."
        }
      ],
      "languageCode": "en-us"
    },
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.8975618,
          "transcript": " I would not working."
        }
      ],
      "languageCode": "en-us"
    },
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "confidence": 0.8619629,
          "transcript": " Is it going through?"
        }
      ],
      "languageCode": "en-us"
    },
```

Comment: You miss the closing `)` of your print

Comment: Thank you. But still, code doesn't work :( @martineau

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: In that case update your question.

Answer (score 1):

You missed that `alternatives` contains a `list` of `dict`.

```
print(output['alternatives'][0]['transcript']
# There is a list here ------^
```

Comment: still something missing 

**IndentationError: expected an indented block**

Comment: @PiotrSzymański Indent your `print` statement with 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
for output in data['results']:
    print(output['alternatives']['transcript']
```

`print()` needs to be indented correctly. In other words: move your `print` statement below `output`

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solve it:

```
for output in data['results']:
    print(output['alternatives'][0]['transcript'])
```